# Clear all ZipArchive entries

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I have a problem using the ZipArchive class in UWP c#...
While using it to write files in a zip file, I noticed the following:
If you select an already generated file (With the savefilepicker) to replace it with a new version, that the ZipArchive adds the new files instead of replacing the files...

Trying to solve this, I tried deleting all ZipArchiveEntries by using:

```
ZipArchiveEntry.Delete();
```

But if I use this while iterating using foreach/for/enumerator.MoveNext() - loops
I get the typical "collection modified, iteration may not continue" error...

My latest version is:

```
using (var enumerator = _archive.Entries.GetEnumerator()) {
    while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
        var item = enumerator.Current;
        item.Delete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem, but if it's the most efficient, I don't know...

```
do {
    _archive.Entries[0].Delete();
} while (_archive.Entries.Count > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also had the same problem. In my situation the user selects a target zip-file with the FileSavePicker. 
Now I solved it by creating a temporary ZIP file in the temp-folder

```
var tempZipFile = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync("TempZipFile.zip", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
```

and when added the content to the zip file use

```
await tempZipFile.MoveAndReplaceAsync(zipFileToCreate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a list of the entries and delete them there

```
foreach(var entry = _archive.Entries.ToList()) {
    entry.Delete();
}
```